# 500 Internal Server Error with ColdFusion Insert to Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coldfusion

```
<title>
    UIOWA UIData
</title>

<link href="/magazine/new/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateForm()
    {   
    if (document.Form.PostedDate.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter the date the data was posted (mm/dd/yy).");
        document.Form.PostedDate.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.Form.DataImage.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please insert the data image.");
        document.Form.DataImage.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.Form.Source.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter the Source of the data.");
        document.Form.Source.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>


    <style type="text/css"> 
    body { color: #666; }
    .main { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }
    th { color: #333; }
    input { height: auto; padding: 5px!important; color: #333; }
    select { color: #333; }
    td {width: 160px; overflow: hidden;}
    p { text-align: center;}
</style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="../textValidator.js" ></script>   
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="madmin.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


<div class="main">

<div style="background-color:black"><img src="Images/newlogo3.png"   width="400" height="120" alt="" style="margin-left:20px"/></div>
<h2>
    UIData Database Insert Form
<cfif StructKeyExists(URL, "message")>
        <cfoutput><small>#URL.message#</small></cfoutput>
 </cfif>
</h2>

<FORM ACTION="UIDataActionInsert.cfm" name="Form" id="Form" onSubmit="return   validateForm();" METHOD="Post">

<table border="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td align="center"><p>Date Posted (mm/dd/yy):</p></td>
 <td colspan="3"><INPUT NAME="PostedDate" TYPE="text" id="PostedDate"   SIZE="100%"  MAXLENGTH="400"></td></tr>

   <tr>
     <td align="center">Data Image:</td>
     <td><input name="DataImage" type="text" id="DataImage" Size="100%">   </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="center"><p>Source:</p></td>
  <td colspan="3"><INPUT NAME="Source" TYPE="text" id="Source" Size="100%"   MAXLENGTH = "400" ></td></tr>


  <td align="center"><p>Hyperlink:</p></td>
  <td colspan="3"><INPUT NAME="HyperLink" TYPE="text" id="HyperLink" Size="100%" MAXLENGTH = "400" ></td></tr>
</table>
   <p>
   <BR>
    <INPUT class="btn" TYPE="reset" NAME="ResetForm" onClick="resetFields();" VALUE="Clear Form">
    <INPUT class="btn primary" TYPE="submit" NAME="SubmitForm" VALUE="Submit Data">
  </p>
   <br>
   <p>
  <a href="https://mysite/administration/UIData/index.cfm">Go back to index</a> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my code for the form to insert into my database, however whenever it is submitted I get a 500 Internal Server Error, I am not seeing what I am doing wrong, Dreamweaver is marking my Form initialization as invalid??

And then here is my Insert Action, I'm not seeing what would be causing this to proc an error.

```
<cfquery NAME="AddData" datasource='UIAAWeb'>
Insert Into UIData(PostedDate, DataImage, Source, HyperLink)

Values('#Form.PostedDate#', '#Form.DataImage#', '#Form.Source#', '#Form.HyperLink#');
</cfquery>



<!--, PostedDate, DataImage, Source, Hyperlink---->



<cfquery name="getID" datasource="UIAAWeb">
select * from UIData
where DataImage = '#Form.DataImage#'
</cfquery>
<cfoutput query="getID"><cflocation url="index.cfm?message=DataImage   '#DataImage#' With ID #DataID# Successfully Created"></cfoutput>
```

Comment: `Dreamweaver is marking my Form initialization as invalid??` - What do you mean by this?

Comment: Can't you try the URL in your browser after clearing the cache?

Comment: dreamweaver has the option to highlight invalid code and the option is highlighting my form

Comment: Can you try renaming your `Form` tag's name from `Form` to something else?

Comment: i tried to remove it and it still gave the error

Comment: Troubleshoot one step at a time.  Start with the select query.  Use a static string instead of the form variable.  If that succeeds, try the insert with static values.  If that succeeds, start using form variables.

Comment: Also, during testing 1) Comment out things like cflocation or it may redirect before you can see the errors. 2) Assuming you are working in a Dev environment, you should enable robust exceptions in the CF Admin so you can actually *see* any errors on screen.

Comment: This code is very dangerous. You need to use `<cfqueryparam>`

Comment: Can you paste for us the actual error you are receiving?